# String vibration under periodic boundry conditions

Tags: string, boundary-conditions, vibrations, molecular-dynamics

I wish to known which are the vibration modes (in case that they exist) of an string vibrating under periodical boundary conditions (PBC).

The question is related to molecular dynamics simulations of polymers simulated in a cubic box under PBC. The polymer is not homogeneous, has internal movements and the ability to stretch. Clearly, there is no need to consider this in the answer, but if it could be considered it would be even better.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure if it'll work but you can try using the finite difference method.